# EF Core simple logging with In-Memory database

Tags: entity-framework-core

I tried [EF Core simple logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging) with SQL Server and Sqlite. It's working fine.

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    //optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source= (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=SamuraiAppDataFirstLook");
    // optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source = SamuraiAppDataFirstLook.sqlite");
    optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(new Guid().ToString());

    optionsBuilder.LogTo(logMessage =>
        {
            Debugger.Break();
            Debug.WriteLine(logMessage);
            Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
        },
        new[] {
          DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name }, LogLevel.Information
    );

    optionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors();
    optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
}
```

But when I tried with an In-Memory database, it's not working.

Is this by design? Or am I missing something?

A full working sample to reproduce the problem is [here on github](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/EfCoreTuts/tree/main/src/Ef040001_Samurai).

The [Debugger.Break() here](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/EfCoreTuts/blob/f7f063b9d696b00349ab822ac75e1e1cbd3a1bf6/src/Ef040001_Samurai/SamuraiApp.Data/SamuraiContext.cs#L24) is not hit, if [I use the inMemory database here](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/EfCoreTuts/blob/f7f063b9d696b00349ab822ac75e1e1cbd3a1bf6/src/Ef040001_Samurai/SamuraiApp.Data/SamuraiContext.cs#L20).

But if use SQL Server or [Sqlite](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/EfCoreTuts/blob/f7f063b9d696b00349ab822ac75e1e1cbd3a1bf6/src/Ef040001_Samurai/SamuraiApp.Data/SamuraiContext.cs#L19) provider, then it does break at the debugger break as expected.

So what am I missing? Is it that the simple logging is not supported for In-Memory databases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inmemory provider is not a relational provider, so does not execute DbCommands. So nothing to log.